# iOS Phonegap Upload and Download error (cordova js version: 3.8.0)

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am working on a project where I need to do 2 things:

1. download media files
2. upload picture taken by camera

In Android both works awesome either jelly beans, kitkat or lollipop. But in iOS both didn't worked.

1. Download media files:

   In Android I had used download option of the file-transfer plugin... and in path I had given:

   `var fileURL = '/sdcard/'+dynamic_file_name;`

   so after download completes I can view the downloaded file by going to my sdcard in Android.

   But in iOS I tried a lot like:

   ```
   var fileURL = cordova.file.documentsDirectory+dynamic_file_name;
   var fileURL = fileSystem.root.toURL() + "/"+dynamic_file_name;
   var fileURL = cordova.file.dataDirectory+dynamic_file_name;
   var fileURL = cordova.file.syncedDataDirectory+dynamic_file_name;
   ```

   While using above I do get download complete message but when I go to videos or audio files in device I don't see the file downloaded (FYI, when I try the code in simulator, by going to the path it downloaded in app, I can see the file downloaded but in device as iOS don't have such device manager to see the downloaded file) .
2. Upload Image:

   In Android I was sending image binary in the start, it was sending it to the server, but it wasn't sending it from ios (DATA_URL)

   Then I started uploading image to the server using file-transfer upload plugin and sending image as (FILE_URI), it worked perfect again in Android but iOS is not sending image to the server.

   One thing I know is after camera takes snapshot it is saved in tmp directory of the app but I don't know why iOS is not uploading file.